# Least squares regression line not matching scatterplot

Tags: r

I am trying to figure out residual distances for a length-mass association, and am running into an issue where the predicted values line does not match the points on the scatterplot at all, although I believe I am using the correct code. I've attached a picture of the plot I'm getting... any ideas as to what's going wrong? 
[image: Least squares regression plot]

```
logTL<-log10(bd.1$TL)
logMass<-log10(bd.1$mass)

#linear relation bt log TL and log mass
lma<-lm(logMass~logTL)
summary(lma)

#plot and fit line to data
plot(logMass, logTL,xlab="log (base 10) total length", ylab="log (base 10) mass")
abline(coefficients(lma))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should exchange the order of `logTL` and `logMass` in your plot, i.e.,

```
plot(logTL, logMass, xlab="log (base 10) total length", ylab="log (base 10) mass")
```

since you did regression of `logMass` with respect to `logTL`, i.e., `lma<-lm(logMass~logTL)`

Otherwise, you can adapt it in another way, i.e., `abline(1/coefficients(lma))`.